# Struts2 Locale(I18N) not Working for Indian Language "Tamil"

Tags: java, struts2

I am developing struts 2 and spring web application which supports three languages English, Chinese and Tamil, I have configured "struts.custom.i18n.resources" with three files named "global.properties, global_zh_CN.properties, global_ta_IN.properties". Language English and Tamil Works Fine, But for When i select tamil always shows English Labels only. Is there any other ways to get support for tamil language. Kindly Help me to Resolve this.

Comment: can you share exact issue what you are facing?

Comment: Internationalization not working for locale "ta_IN" in struts2. I have three resource files such as "global.properties, global_zh_CN.properties, global_ta_IN.properties" in my resource folder. My code works for locale(s) like zh_CN, en_US etc., (i.e) If i request Chinese Language from my web page i can get response page in Chinese Language. But when i select tamil language, i can't get tamil language, instead of tamil i am getting page with default locale english language. Is there any way to get response page as my tamil language support.